# Data Warehouse design

Tags: sql, database

I understand the concept of a Data Warehouse for online analytical processing.

My question relates specifically to querying a Data Warehouse.  What is the difference between SQL that is used for Data Warehouses and SQL that is used for Data Warehouses?  I am trying to understand if there is a variation of SQL that is used specifically for Data Warehouse type systems or whether "multi dimensional Data Mining" tools are simply SQL tools at their implementation level.

For example, Object Oriented SQL and Object Relational SQL are documented as supersets of the SQL language.  Are one of these used more in a hypercube (multi dimensional) data model?

Comment: Which vendor are you referring to that has "multi-dimensional Data Mining" tools? If it's is Rocket Software with U2, that means something very different than what others may mean.

Comment: Could you reword `What is the difference between SQL that is used for Data Warehouses and SQL that is used for Data Warehouses?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use T-SQL to query OLTP databases and [MDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_Expressions) to query cubes (OLAP)

Comment: Thanks.  This was what I was looking for.  All the web pages I have read talk about Data Warehouses and OLAP as view only systems.  If you have a system that co-ordinates information from multiple system but holds information itself then would you classify this as a Data Warehouse?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you mention data mining.  Querying languages, such as T-SQL and MDX in SQL Server, are used when you know what patterns exist in the data, and you want to find the statistical results.  Data mining is used as artificial intelligence, when there are patterns within the data that you do not know about, and the software searches the database and discovers those patterns for you.  When utilizing the SQL Server stack, SSAS offers this feature.